# I added sqlserver datastore to geoserver but its dont show layer

Tags: python, java, sql-server, gis, geoserver

hi im tried to add SQLServer datastore to Geoserver for some reason.
i install a geoserver sqlserver plugin. and run it
after that i added SQLServer datastore to my Geoserver and select my layer from my datastore
so far everything was good
but when i tried to get view my layer from layer preview it does not show anything
and when i tried to get information on map i get this error

`HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.SurfaceData`

i use Geoserver version 19.0 and its own extension from Geoserver site
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: which version of Java are you using? are you sure you installed the correct version of the plugin?

Comment: i use OpenJDK 17 and Geoserver version 19. i downlaoded sqlserver extension from geoserver site for version 19

Comment: Java 17 is not (yet) supported by GeoServer try with Java 11 - if that fixes the issue please open a jira ticket to make sure this is fixed in the change to 17